# Sympy taking forever to compute for given set of equations

Tags: sympy, ode, symbolic-math

Wanted to solve a system of ODEs for equilibrium points. But this is taking forever to compute on google colab. Am I doing something wrong.

```
from sympy import solve
from sympy.abc import c, d, e, q, m, p, u, C, D, E, M

solve([c*C*(1-C-D-M) - e*C - (d*D+ m+p*d*M)*C + (1-p)*(p*q+(1-p)*c)*(1-C-D-M)*M , p*(p*q + (1-p)*c)*(1-C-D-M)*M-(e + u)*D+q*D*(1-C-D-M) , (d*D+m)*C - (e+p*u)*M ], C,D,M, dict=True)
```

Kept it running for a long time and it still doesnt compute

Comment: You are asking for the symbolic solution of a system of quadratic equations with symbolic coefficients. While there will be at most 8 solutions, the expressions in the coefficients can blow up in size. Also, does sympy have a Gröbner or other solver that can transform polynomial systems into triangular form in some efficient way? Conclusion: Take a numerical solver.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using SymPy to get to explicit expressions for some of the solutions more quickly but I think that the nontrivial equilibria cannot be representing using simple expressions. (There are at least 3 real solutions but also 4 more that are possibly non-real depending on the values of the parameters.)

It can be surprising that when there are symbolic coefficients even linear systems of equations can have very complicated solution expressions but the problems blow up even more quickly in the case of polynomial systems. You have here 3 polynomial equations involving the 3 unknowns `M`, `C` and `D` but where the coefficients are symbolic expressions that are themselves polynomial in some parameters:

```
In [131]: for eq in eqs: print(eq)
C*c*(-C - D - M + 1) - C*e - C*(D*d + M*d*p + m) + M*(1 - p)*(c*(1 - p) + p*q)*(-C - D - M + 1)
D*q*(-C - D - M + 1) - D*(e + u) + M*p*(c*(1 - p) + p*q)*(-C - D - M + 1)
C*(D*d + m) - M*(e + p*u)
```

When you call `solve` with a polynomial system like this SymPy will attempt to compute a Groebner basis and then form radical expressions for the roots of the resulting triangular system of polynomials. This is slow in this case because the polynomials involved will have many terms due to the high number of symbolic parameters in your equations. You can think of the complexity of the solution expressions and the runtime needed to compute them as being probably worse than exponential in the number of parameters and unknowns so each extra parameter brings significant additional complexity. One possibility that is often useful for a situation like this is to substitute numeric values for most parameters and consider the effect of one or two parameters at a time.

We can attempt a somewhat more direct approach here though. Since the third equation is linear in M we can use it to eliminate `M` from the other two. We can do this using resultants to preserve the polynomial form of the equations.

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import c, d, e, q, m, p, u, C, D, M

eqs = [
    c*C*(1-C-D-M) - e*C - (d*D+ m+p*d*M)*C + (1-p)*(p*q+(1-p)*c)*(1-C-D-M)*M,
    p*(p*q + (1-p)*c)*(1-C-D-M)*M-(e + u)*D+q*D*(1-C-D-M) ,
    (d*D+m)*C - (e+p*u)*M,
]

# First eliminate M from the first two equations

eq1 = resultant(eqs[0], eqs[2], M)
eq2 = resultant(eqs[1], eqs[2], M)

# Now factor eq1 and take the two factors in turn:

coeff, [(eq1_1, _), (eq1_2, _)] = factor_list(eq1, C)
```

Then the first equation factors having one simple factor and one complicated factor:

```
In [134]: print(eq1_1)
C

In [135]: print(eq1_2)
C*(-D**2*c*d**2*p**2 + 2*D**2*c*d**2*p - D**2*c*d**2 + D**2*d**2*p**2*q - D**2*d**2*p*q - D*c*d*e*p**2 + 2*D*c*d*e*p - 2*D*c*d*e - 2*D*c*d*m*p**2 + 4*D*c*d*m*p - 2*D*c*d*m - D*c*d*p**3*u + 2*D*c*d*p**2*u - 2*D*c*d*p*u - D*d**2*e*p - D*d**2*p**2*u + D*d*e*p**2*q - D*d*e*p*q + 2*D*d*m*p**2*q - 2*D*d*m*p*q + D*d*p**3*q*u - D*d*p**2*q*u - c*e**2 - c*e*m*p**2 + 2*c*e*m*p - 2*c*e*m - 2*c*e*p*u - c*m**2*p**2 + 2*c*m**2*p - c*m**2 - c*m*p**3*u + 2*c*m*p**2*u - 2*c*m*p*u - c*p**2*u**2 - d*e*m*p - d*m*p**2*u + e*m*p**2*q - e*m*p*q + m**2*p**2*q - m**2*p*q + m*p**3*q*u - m*p**2*q*u) - D**2*c*d*e*p**2 + 2*D**2*c*d*e*p - D**2*c*d*e - D**2*c*d*p**3*u + 2*D**2*c*d*p**2*u - D**2*c*d*p*u + D**2*d*e*p**2*q - D**2*d*e*p*q + D**2*d*p**3*q*u - D**2*d*p**2*q*u + D*c*d*e*p**2 - 2*D*c*d*e*p + D*c*d*e + D*c*d*p**3*u - 2*D*c*d*p**2*u + D*c*d*p*u - D*c*e**2 - D*c*e*m*p**2 + 2*D*c*e*m*p - D*c*e*m - 2*D*c*e*p*u - D*c*m*p**3*u + 2*D*c*m*p**2*u - D*c*m*p*u - D*c*p**2*u**2 - D*d*e**2 - D*d*e*p**2*q + D*d*e*p*q - 2*D*d*e*p*u - D*d*p**3*q*u + D*d*p**2*q*u - D*d*p**2*u**2 + D*e*m*p**2*q - D*e*m*p*q + D*m*p**3*q*u - D*m*p**2*q*u + c*e**2 + c*e*m*p**2 - 2*c*e*m*p + c*e*m + 2*c*e*p*u + c*m*p**3*u - 2*c*m*p**2*u + c*m*p*u + c*p**2*u**2 - e**3 - e**2*m - 2*e**2*p*u - e*m*p**2*q + e*m*p*q - 2*e*m*p*u - e*p**2*u**2 - m*p**3*q*u + m*p**2*q*u - m*p**2*u**2
```

Each of these factors is linear in `C`. The first factor gives solutions having `C = 0` which is not too complicated:

```
In [137]: eq_D_1 = resultant(eq1_1, eq2, C)

In [139]: print(eq_D_1)
-D**2*e**2*q - 2*D**2*e*p*q*u - D**2*p**2*q*u**2 - D*e**3 - 2*D*e**2*p*u + D*e**2*q - D*e**2*u - D*e*p**2*u**2 + 2*D*e*p*q*u - 2*D*e*p*u**2 + D*p**2*q*u**2 - D*p**2*u**3
```

This is a quadratic in `D` now with both `M` and `C` eliminated and it factorises:

```
In [142]: eq_D_1 = resultant(eq1_1, eq2, C)

In [143]: print(eq_D_1)
-D**2*e**2*q - 2*D**2*e*p*q*u - D**2*p**2*q*u**2 - D*e**3 - 2*D*e**2*p*u + D*e**2*q - D*e**2*u - D*e*p**2*u**2 + 2*D*e*p*q*u - 2*D*e*p*u**2 + D*p**2*q*u**2 - D*p**2*u**3

In [144]: print(eq_D_1.factor())
-D*(e + p*u)**2*(D*q + e - q + u)
```

We see here in the factorisation that we get solutions `D = 0` and another simple expression for `D` so this is easily solvable:

```
In [145]: for r in roots(eq_D_1, D): print(r)
(-e + q - u)/q
0
```

So this gives what are probably the relatively trivial equilibria for your ODEs:

```
C = 0, D = 0
C = 0, D = (-e + q - u)/q
```

From there you can substitute into the original third equation to find the corresponding values of `M`.

That was the simple factor for `C` but the nonzero `C` case (`eq1_2`) gave us a much more complicated expression although it is still linear in `C`. We can use that to eliminate `C` from `eq2` again but it leads to a quintic with coefficients that are multivariate polynomials with many terms:

```
In [150]: eq_D_2 = resultant(eq1_2, eq2, C)

In [151]: len(str(eq_D_2))
Out[151]: 67880

In [152]: degree(eq_D_2, D)
Out[152]: 5
```

The elimination here generates a large polynomial result. It is not possible to show the full result here because it needs 70000 characters to print the expression. Since it is a quintic it has at least one real root if its leading coefficient is nonzero but depending on the values of the parameters might have 1, 3 or 5 real roots. Factorising the leading coefficient reveals potential values of the parameters that would make it zero representing possible degenerate cases for your ODE system like `d=0` and `p=1` etc:

```
In [153]: print(LC(eq_D_2, D).factor())
-d**4*(e + p*u)**2*(p - 1)**2*(-c*p + c + p*q)*(-c*e*p**2 + c*e - c*p**3*u + c*p**2*u - c*p*u + c*u + e*p**2*q + e*p*q - e*q + p**3*q*u)In [35]: [r.n(3) for r in real_roots(sqf_part(condition_u))]
Out[35]: [-4.64, -4.41, -2.83, -2.0, -1.1, -0.309, 2.83]
```

We can also factorise the constant coefficient which shows parameter values such that there will be an equilibrium with `D = 0`:

```
In [155]: print(eq_D_2.subs(D, 0).factor())
-m*p*(e + p*u)**3*(-c*p + c + p*q)*(d*m*p + e**2 + 2*e*m + e*p*u + m**2 + m*p*u)*(-c*e - c*m*p**2 + 2*c*m*p - c*m - c*p*u + e**2 + e*m + e*p*u + m*p**2*q - m*p*q + m*p*u)
```

Unfortunately the full quintic polynomial does not factorise though. Since the coefficients are symbolic it is most likely impossible to give an explicit expression for the roots for `D` in radicals due to the Abel-Ruffini theorem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem

That does not mean that further symbolic analysis is impossible but just that you would need to work with `eq_D_2` as an implicit representation of the 5 nontrivial equilibria. This is what I did above by investigating the leading and constant coefficients: we can answer some questions without having an explicit representation for the solutions. Another example is that you could study the discriminant of `eq_D_2` to look for bifurcations. Since `eq_D_2` is already quite complicated though its discriminant is likely to be very complicated (I haven't waited long enough to compute it). Substituting values for most of the parameters can make it manageable while still allowing enough parameters to be able to do some symbolic calculations:

```
In [22]: p = eq_D_2.subs({c:1, d:1, e:1, m:1, p:S.Half, q:1})

In [23]: print(p.as_poly(D))
Poly((-3*u**3/64 - 7*u**2/32 - 5*u/16 - 1/8)*D**5 + (-13*u**4/64 - 95*u**3/64 - 121*u**2/32 - 61*u/16 - 9/8)*D**4 + (-17*u**5/64 - 45*u**4/16 - 355*u**3/32 - 319*u**2/16 - 123*u/8 - 13/4)*D**3 + (-7*u**6/64 - 105*u**5/64 - 307*u**4/32 - 883*u**3/32 - 641*u**2/16 - 207*u/8 - 17/4)*D**2 + (-u**7/64 - 19*u**6/64 - 75*u**5/32 - 315*u**4/32 - 1487*u**3/64 - 955*u**2/32 - 289*u/16 - 25/8)*D - u**5/32 - 23*u**4/64 - 99*u**3/64 - 101*u**2/32 - 49*u/16 - 9/8, D, domain='QQ[u]')
```

It is still not possible to find explicit expressions for the roots but we can see for example when we might have two equilibria have the same value of `D` (a necessary condition for some kinds of bifurcation):

```
In [29]: condition_u = discriminant(p, D)

In [30]: print(condition_u)
-731*u**44/281474976710656 - 14725*u**43/70368744177664 - 572343*u**42/70368744177664 - 1783987*u**41/8796093022208 - 512245981*u**40/140737488355328 - 3516979779*u**39/70368744177664 - 38342595905*u**38/70368744177664 - 169849860685*u**37/35184372088832 - 9922328400643*u**36/281474976710656 - 7514263765529*u**35/35184372088832 - 37706915327127*u**34/35184372088832 - 38621890590577*u**33/8796093022208 - 247725748255785*u**32/17592186044416 - 33871082073201*u**31/1099511627776 - 14559713680375*u**30/1099511627776 + 72484025821341*u**29/274877906944 + 1691040049899725*u**28/1099511627776 + 744739825278829*u**27/137438953472 + 1873879802940423*u**26/137438953472 + 790377140634213*u**25/34359738368 + 765561123041415*u**24/68719476736 - 95881842285765*u**23/1073741824 - 895486823669595*u**22/2147483648 - 631859584199745*u**21/536870912 - 11007978134482185*u**20/4294967296 - 2471035242520959*u**19/536870912 - 3758989353569865*u**18/536870912 - 1225969070952887*u**17/134217728 - 2758070287962323*u**16/268435456 - 167464753858269*u**15/16777216 - 140453816987647*u**14/16777216 - 25401129162115*u**13/4194304 - 63429945352185*u**12/16777216 - 4292989414277*u**11/2097152 - 2042259741143*u**10/2097152 - 217873634941*u**9/524288 - 169503772283*u**8/1048576 - 1851493425*u**7/32768 - 34114811*u**6/2048 - 30226215*u**5/8192 - 4040889*u**4/8192 - 6115*u**3/512 + 2853*u**2/512 + 7*u/64 - 23/256
```

This gives candidate values of `u` for which a collision of equilibria is possible:

```
In [35]: [r.n(3) for r in real_roots(sqf_part(condition_u))]
Out[35]: [-4.64, -4.41, -2.83, -2.0, -1.1, -0.309, 2.83]
```